# In Excel how can I pull just the state from a cell which has a complete address?

Tags: excel, function, search, replace

I have a list of complete addresses, each in their own cell that I would like to pull just the state abbreviations from.

- Cell 1: 345 Left Ln, Nowhere, TX 340598
- Cell 2: 839 Right Dr, Glendale - NC 3498
- Cell 3: 0983 Alphabet St, Boston MA - 23409

I have a list/range of cells that has the state abbreviations, I just don't know how to search each cell for all 50 of the abreviations and then output it. The other problem with search replace is that some of the abrivations show up in the cell naturally as a street name such as "Glendale" in the second example above has AL in it which is state abbreviation but not a state. Unfortunately the addresses are NOT formatted in a uniform manner and can have different punctuation through out.

I would be ok with an output of AL, NC for the second address in the example above because it wouldn't be too hard to separate out the few cases which have multiple states in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples the state abbreviation always has a space either side so you can use this formula, assuming address in A2 and list of state abbreviations in Z2:Z50

`=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(" "&$Z$2:$Z$50&" "," "&A2&" "),$Z$2:$Z$50)`

copy formula down to get results for every address

If state abbreviation in address will always be in CAPS and list of abbreviations is always in CAPS then FIND function will be preferable to SEARCH as FIND is not case-sensitive so less chance of a "false positive"

**Update:**

Given your comments - state abbreviations may not be upper case, may not have spaces either side.....but presumably the "true" state will be the **last** match in the cell? To get that try this formula for any version of Excel

`=MID(A2,MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($Z$2:$Z$50,A2)),SEARCH($Z$2:$Z$50,A2))),2)`

....or this one for Excel 2007 or later versions

`=MID(A2,MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH($Z$2:$Z$50,A2),"")),2)`

Those are "array formulas" that need to be confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. Paste formula in cell then press F2 key to select formula - then hold down CTRL and SHIFT keys while pressing ENTER. If done correctly you will see curly braces like { and } around the formula and hopefully get the correct result. Do that for the first formula then copy down column.

If you have Excel 2010 you can do it more simply with a non-array formula using AGGREGATE function like this:

`=MID(A2,AGGREGATE(14,6,SEARCH($Z$2:$Z$50,A2),1),2)`

Comment: Unfortunetly the abreviations don't always have spaces on either side and are not always capitlaized. Some ar "-Nc" , " me,".

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, the function worked on most of them but theres over 1000 records and some are formatted strange. Any idea how to handle instances where their might be 2 occurrences of state abbreviations in a cell that doesn't have the state abbreviation with spaces on either side? Like AL and TX can been found in "123 Glendale Rd, TX-342930.

Comment: OK, in most cases then it will be the **last** match in the cell? I edited my answer.....

Comment: Awesome! Looks like this works, hard to say 100% with so many entries. Some of the address don't have an abbreviation it turns out or a sate at all but that's easy to filter out. Thanks again for the help.